# Arch Linux unknown wireless card

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux

I am currently working on an Arch linux build. I am using the 4-1-14 version from a compact disc, which I downloaded from the torrent magnet and verified after burning. I am going to need to use wireless internet in order to download some things I need with Pacman. This is where my issue comes in:

When I type `lspci` my wireless network card is labeled as unknown. I am using an older linksys PCI card that I removed from an old dell, and I am trying to use it in this HP machine that I have. When I got into the hardware detection tool from the Arch linux disc, the card is labeled as `unknown:unknown`

What must I do in order to get this card to function? I can provide the serial number from the device, but I will have to open up the box and I am trying to avoid doing this because I was having some issues with my video card earlier and I finally got it to work. What should I do?

Comment: Definitely see if you can get some help on #archlinux on the freenode IRC network. I'd link you to a webclient, but they're all blocked on my work network. All my archlinux installs have been done over ethernet because wireless can be a pain sometimes.

Comment: Can you at least get the PCI IDs of the card ? If not, your card may be damaged or incompatible with your motherboard (wrong BIOS settings maybe ?).

Comment: As a first stop you could try running `update-pciids` and see if a more recent ID database knows your card. In any case, running `lspci -vv` should put out the hardware ID of the device which, in turn, should give you some results in any search engine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link to the wireless section of Arch wiki Beginner's Guide.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners%27_guide#Wireless_2

Most scenarios are contemplated there. If you follow the guide carefully, and read the relevant links, this should be all you need to get your wifi to work.

On a side note: I had an unrecognized wirelss card issue a while ago. The card was supported, but the connector was dusty and the card did not get properly recognized till I cleaned carefully all the connectors with a solvent.